# Is there a way to send messages to every member on a discord server? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I want to send a message to everyone on a discord server, except one. How can I do it? Because, with my code it checks if it's that user over and over. (and it would be best if this could happen when the bot gets online (on_ready)) Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems like you want to make a spam bot. I recommend you to explain a bit more about your project since it seems against the discord TOS

Comment: No, I want to make a bot that is sending out news about the server only to a certain people. Not a spambot.

Comment: Create a private channel where you can ping everyone if you want to share news like that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it, but Im not providing an example here.
**Mass-messaging users with a bot is considered spamming by Discord and its guidelines.**

EDIT: You also aren't allowed to do it cause you would go over the rate-limit Discord is allowing a bot to do at the same time.

I suggest you just create a [newsletter via email](https://www.stylefactoryproductions.com/blog/how-to-create-an-e-newsletter).